# Filter a list in an inner foreach loop based on ID of outerloop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have an outer and an inner foreach loop, each looping on a list.  The inner loop needs to be filtered based on a current value of the outer loop. I need some help with the syntax of the where clause on the inner loop.

```
@foreach (var item1 in Model.list1)
{
    ...
    @foreach (var item2 in Model.list2.Where( item2.item1id = item1.item1id ))
    {
        ...
    }
   ...
}
```

What is the correct syntax for that .Where statement?

Thanks!!

Comment: ok that was simpler than I was trying to make it!  If  you want to put that in an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way LINQ works in terms of these predicates is that you have to assign a variable as the element of list2 you are enumerating through, so the correct syntax would be:

```
@foreach (var item2 in Model.list2.Where(itemFromList2 => itemFromList2.item1id == item1.item1id))
```

As list is processed, `Where()` assigns each item to `itemFromList2` and uses that to compare.

Comment: marked as correct for the extra explanations,  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be something like this:

```
@foreach (var item2 in Model.list2.Where( a=> a.item1id == item1.item1id))
...
```